# Getting the external hard-drive faster into standby

Tags: power-management, external-hdd, standby

Currently, my external hard-drive is going into standby after 15 minutes of inactivity. How can I reduce this period to e.g. 5 minutes?

Using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with Gnome Shell.

Thanks in advance!